# How to save criteria in Google Finance Stock Screener?

Tags: google

After customizing the criteria in [Google Finance Stock Screener](https://www.google.ca/finance?#stockscreener), I would like to save my selection for later use, but I am unable to. Is there a way to achieve that?

Note : I have tried bookmarking the page, but it doesn't work. Also, I am logged in using gmail account and I have disabled every plugin my browser could potentially be using on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but you can do the following:
(1) Right click on the right pointing arrow next to the "1-20 of xx rows" message at the bottom right of the table, and select "Copy link location"

(2) Paste that into the location

(3) At the end of the pasted text there is a "&output=json", delete that and everything after it.

(4) hit enter

What you get is a page that displays the set of securities returned by and in a very similar display to the "stock screener" without the UI elements to change your selections. You can bookmark this page.